# m7b5 chord in a progression?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

> E | F# | G#m7 | D#m7
>
> C#m7 | D#7 | G#m7 | B
>
> E | Gdim | G#m7 | Fm7-5
>
> C#m7 | D#7 | G#m7

I'm sure that Gdim serve as a diminished seventh to G#m7, but what purpose does that Fm7-5 serves?

it's from a japanese [song](https://youtu.be/A2Pk5-o019k?t=60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of an overall chromatic root movement. Consider this variation on how the progression could be played (with some enharmonic alterations for clarity of movement in each voice):

```
X:0
T:Chromatic root movement
K:none
M:4/4
L:1/2
"E"[^GBe] "Edim7"[=G_B_de] | "G#m7"[^F^GB^d] "Fm7b5"[=F_AB^d] | "C#m7"[=E^GB^c] "D#7"[^D=G_B^c]
```